# How to display comma in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

I am setting this array, and for the most part it works properly in my site. NOTE: This is a Joomla site and a VirtueMart PHP file for the email that the customer receives when ordering a product.

```
$addressBTOrder = array('email{br}', 'company{br}', 'title', 'first_name', 'last_name{br}', 'address_1{br}', 'address_2{br}', 'city', 'virtuemart_state_id', 'zip{br}', 'virtuemart_country_id{br}', 'phone_1{br}', 'phone_2{br}');
```

However, I need to add a comma (,) after CITY in the array to actually display a comma in the final output. If I just put the comma after city:

```
'city,'
```

... it does not work and the city output just doesn't display at all. I also tried the hex value for comma (%2c) but it didn't work either.

Here is the code that is creating the output:

```
<?php
        foreach ($addressBTOrder as $fieldname) {
            $fieldinfo = explode('{',$fieldname);
            if (!empty($this->userfields['fields'][$fieldinfo[0]]['value'])) { ?>
                <span class="values vm2<?php echo '-' . $this->userfields['fields'][$fieldinfo[0]]['name'] ?>" ><?php echo $this->escape($this->userfields['fields'][$fieldinfo[0]]['value']) ?></span> <?php
                if (isset($fieldinfo[1]) && $fieldinfo[1] == 'br}') { ?>
                    <br class="clear" /> <?php
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

What code do I need to put there to display a comma in the final output? For instance, I am making the line break work by using {br}. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like you are pushing through some kind of framework and it's eating the comma.  Because I don't know any system that uses {br} and your description of the '.' vanishing is too odd

Comment: ^^+ you have shown no output code, just an array, so we cant even guess at that issue

Comment: Edited to add the code I am using to display the output

Comment: That `{br}` thing is super weird. Why not just put a newline in, ie `"email\n"` and use `nl2br()` when displaying?

Comment: I do not know php very well and I modified existing code to make it work for my needs. Although I do not understand it, the {br} totally works for this. In fact, everything works perfectly except needing the comma after city.

Comment: I'm guessing `{br}` is a Joomla thing.

Comment: And joomla is probably related to why your code isn't working.

Comment: @Barmar it's not, OP is just using it as a suffix indicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm getting from your code is that you want to specify some sort of suffix after each output of the corresponding *userfield* value.

A differentapproach is to make use of your CSS classes. This means you can properly style your content without adding extra elements.

For example, going back to your original array without anything extra

```
$addressBTOrder = ['email', 'company', 'title', 'city', ...];

foreach ($addressBTOrder as $field) :
$userField = $this->userfields['fields'][$field];
if (!empty($userField['value'])) : ?>
<span class="values vm2-<?= $userField['name'] ?>">
  <?= $this->escape($userField['value']) ?>
</span>
<?php endif; endforeach ?>
```

and, since you're already adding CSS classes which I'm guessing are like `vm2-email`, `vm2-company`, etc...

```
.vm2-email, .vm2-company {
  display: block; /* same as adding a newline */
}
.vm2-city:after {
  content: ",";
}
```

---

Original answer here...

I would recommend using a more succinct data format. For example

```
$br = '<br class="clear" />';
$addressBTOrder = [[
    'key' => 'email',
    'suffix' => $br
], [
    'key' => 'company',
    'suffix' => $br
], [
    'key' => 'title',
    'suffix' => ''
], /* etc */ [
    'key' => 'city',
    'suffix' => ','
]];
```

then you can iterate like this...

```
<?php foreach ($addressBTOrder as $field) :
$userField = $this->userfields['fields'][$field['key']];
if (!empty($userField['value'])) : ?>
<span class="values vm2-<?= $userField['name'] ?>">
  <?= $this->escape($userField['value']), $field['suffix'] ?>
</span>
<?php endif; endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I like this approach very much. It's easy to extend it.

Comment: Alright, this works properly except there is a space after "city" (before the comma). For the rest of the fields, that automatic space makes sense so I don't want to remove the spaces after all of them, but is there a way to just remove the space after city? Soooo close, thank you!!

Comment: @BryanEarl I've added what I think is a better solution

Comment: Perfect. That works and having it inside the span is not a problem in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @BryanEarl I edited my answer. You might want to rethink the accept vote unless the latest answer still works for you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're expecting everything before `{` in the array element to be a key in the `$this->userfields['fields']` array. But when you have a comma there, it doesn't match the array keys. So you need to remove the comma before using it as a key. And if it has a comma, you need to add that to the output.

```
    foreach ($addressBTOrder as $fieldname) {
        $fieldinfo = explode('{',$fieldname);
        $name = $fieldinfo[0];
        if ($name[-1] == ",") {
            $comma = ",";
            $name = substr($name, 0, -1);
        } else {
            $comma = "";
        }
        if (!empty($this->userfields['fields'][$name]['value'])) { ?>
            <span class="values vm2<?php echo '-' . $this->userfields['fields'][$name]]['name'] ?>" ><?php echo $this->escape($this->userfields['fields'][$name]['value']) . $comma; ?></span> <?php
            if (isset($fieldinfo[1]) && $fieldinfo[1] == 'br}') { ?>
                <br class="clear" /> <?php
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like OP also wants to output a comma after the "city" user field

Comment: Yeah, I just added that

Comment: Essentially, I only want the comma after "city", no other fields. Does this accomplish that?

Comment: It adds a comma whenver the field name in the array ends with comma.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is very clear to me at this point because I am not good at PHP at all. I struggle to understand it. I thank you very much for your input though, and will give it a try.

Comment: Just tried this one and unfortunately it gives me an error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 1):

It's more clean and easy to design the view exactly you want instead of try to do this with code. For example something like this:

```
<?php if(!empty($this->userfields['fields']['email']['value'])): ?>

<span class="values vm2-email">
   <?= $this->escape($this->userfields['fields']['email']['value']) ?></span>
</span>
<br class="clear" />
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!empty($this->userfields['fields']['city']['value'])): ?>
<span class="values vm2-city">
   <?= $this->escape($this->userfields['fields']['city']['value']) ?>, </span>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!empty($this->userfields['fields']['virtuemart_state_id']['value'])): ?>
<span class="values vm2-virtuemart_state_id">
   <?= $this->escape($this->userfields['fields']['virtuemart_state_id']['value']) ?></span>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this makes much more sense, and is more readable that looping on the array indeed...